# Generating non duplicate items in componentDidMount using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am creating a multipage application. When the user navigates to one of my pages `componentDidMount` triggers and currently generates 4 random numbers within a range I have specified and sends them through my reducer. This eventually comes back in the form of an array.

Within `componentDidMount` I have a loop to call my `generateRandomNumber` function four times. However, if I go to log the output array I get a blank array, which is the initial state for said reducer.

Logging the array in `componentDidUpdate`, or anywhere after the mount returns what I want it to but that doesn't help me in checking for duplicates as I cannot check for duplicates if I am checking against a blank array. Everything should be without delay, but there seems to be an issue with trying to read from `this.props.currentUserList` from within `componentDidMount`.

I need to verify that I am not adding two of the same user into my array, but I need the pre-check to all be done by the time this appears on-screen.

```
//gives me a random user from my array
generateRandomUser() {
  return myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1]
}

//sends 4 randomUsers through my actions to my reducers
generateNewID() {
  let amountOfOptions = 4;

  while (amountOfOptions > 0) {
    let randomUser = this.generateRandomUser();

    if (this.props.currentUserList.length === 0) {
      this.props.setCurrentUser(randomUser);
    } else {
      //this never fires as currentUserList is somehow still == []
      this.checkForDuplicates();
    }

    amountOfOptions--;
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.generateNewID()


  console.log(this.props.currentUserList)
  //returns []
}

componentDidUpdate() {

  console.log(this.props.currentUserList)
  // returns [
  //   user2: {
  //    name: 'name'
  //   },
  //   user4: {
  //    name: 'name'
  //   },
  //   user28: {
  //    name: 'name'
  //   },
  //   user92: {
  //    name: 'name'
  //   }, 
  // ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the implementation of the array. However if the required output is to get 4 random users then instead of of calling setcurrentuser 4 times, you can generate 4 users and then set them at once.

```
generateNewID() {
  let amountOfOptions = 4;
  let randomUserList = [];
  while (amountOfOptions > 0) {
    let randomUser = this.generateRandomUser();
    if (randomUserList.length === 0) {
      randomUserList.push(randomUser);
    } else {
      //this never fires as currentUserList is somehow still == []
      this.checkForDuplicates();
    }
    amountOfOptions--;
  }
  this.setCurrentUser(randomUserList);
}
```

Comment: `//change me to dummy image
let INITIAL_STATE = [];

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  // console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_CURRENT_USER':
      return [...state, action.payload];

    case 'RESET_CURRENT_USER':
      return [];
  }

  return state;
}
`

At the end if `currentUserList` is called in something like an update or within render it gives the proper response.

Comment: Sorry, for clerification:

At the end of the render if `currentUserList` is called it still returns []
However if the component is updated in any way I get what I want within my array. 

My reducer takes in whatever the action throws at it, which in this case is a user, and plugs it in as [...state, action.payload]

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what you are trying to say.